# Triggering click event on an element not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am making an angular app but I have found an instance where I need to use jQuery. I need to click a button which raises a click event on another hidden button. I know this seems odd but I need this functionality because an angular module I am using, ng-file-upload, will not work on styled icons.

My solution was to create two buttons, one hidden, one transparent. I then put the styled icon on the transparent button and made the other button hidden. I then used jQuery to cause the second button to be clicked when the first is clicked. This works fine in modern firefox/chrome but not at all in IE8.

```
<button id="firstClick" class="fa fa-camera-retro"></button>
<button ng-hide="true" id="secondClick" ng-file-select ng-model="files">Upload</button>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#firstClick', function() {
    $('#secondClick').trigger('click');
});
```

I am currently using jQuery version 1.10.2. Any help with this or alternative ways to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: 
I think the problem may have to do with angular-file-select as the secondClick is now firing. However angular-file-select is not. Also I set secondClick to visible and when I click it directly it fires ng-file-select.

Comment: There is no reason this would not work, unless you have multiple elements in the page with the `id` of `firstClick`. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Or you can try $('#secondClick').click();

Comment: I guess you are approaching correctly while developing for IE8, because i got to know that angular is not supporting IE8. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: Nope just one element with the id of firstClick. I cant see this being the problem as it works perfectly in firefox/chrome. I had it orginally as $('#secondClick').click(); but I saw a few posts here that advised to do it this way.

Comment: Can you add this just to make sure it's triggered or not : `jQuery(document).on('click','button',function(){
    console.log('click on '+jQuery(this).attr('id')) ;
}) ;` I don't have an IE8 version to test

Comment: `<button id="firstClick"` may be not in dom yet when you call it. try confirming it by `console.log($('#secondClick').length)`

Comment: @Jai every other part of the site is 100% percent angular, and works perfectly. It is just this one situation where I could not think of an angular solution.

Comment: @PierreGranger it is registering the firstClick but not the second.

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident you can use `angular.element` if you are looking for angular solution.

Comment: @YOU secondClick.length is 1.

Comment: @Jai I had already tried that before I posted this question. Sorry I should have specified that in the question.

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident if you have time to reproduce the issue then you can post a plnkr link. http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: if trigger('click') itself is not working in ie8, you can try mouse events - http://zxcvbnmnbvcxz.com/how-to-work-jquery-trigger-in-ie/

Comment: Could be browser specific to not allowing hidden button to trigger event. So firstly try with a not hidden button. Then if working,  you could find some workaround

Comment: @Jai I will try the jqlite solution and if that doesn't work I will post a plunkr

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident I'm not sure why if jQuery not working, jqlite could fix it. I don't see any reason for that

Comment: @Jai I went to create a plunkr but there is no way to load in angular-file-upload. I dont know if the plunkr will be of much value without this as I believe this is a part of the problem. secondClick is now getting logged in the console when I click firstClick but angular-file-upload is not firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not mentioned the angular version of your app is using. But if you are using `angular 1.3.x` then you have to know that it does not support *IE8* browser anymore.

[docs for IE guide.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

There is a note:

> **Note:** AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.

---

As per your comment:

*every other part of the site is 100% percent angular, and works perfectly. It is just this one situation where I could not think of an angular solution.*

Then i want to suggest you that angular does have a lite version of jQuery in it, called `jqLite`. You can make use of it, like:

```
angular.element('#firstClick').on('click', function() {
    angular.element('#secondClick').trigger('click');
});
```

[Docs for angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: Sorry also should have specified that it is Angular 1.2. I will try it using jqlite

Comment: jqlite made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: You can forward mouse events through elements with good browser support using: http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/**

If you're fortunate enough to not have to work with older browsers then you can get away the pointer-events CSS property.

```
#firstClick {
    pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Comment: `pointer-events` isn't supported on IE<11  http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: You're right - I will update my answer to reflect that and some additional advice for support that far back in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Change the jquery version to lower. By seeing [this](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/issues/222) thread i think version 1.10.2 is not support for ie8. i also tried in jsfiddle and test in ie8 there isissues. when i change to change the version it's working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gsw369/1/)

```
$('#secondClick').click();
```

Comment: but when see in the version of 1.10.2 script. I'm getting error 'Access is denied' in many place for ie8 and also they but like this 
// Support: IE>8